# Is it possible to fold/hide columns of a wide table

Tags: tables

I have a wide table with 15 columns. Each 3 columns should be grouped and viewed together, so I have 5 groups. The first group should be fixed and viewed all times.

Is it possible to make a foldable table showing only 2 groups? The first group and a selectable group of the other four.

My users don't like turned tables. 
Printing the resulting PDF will have the first group in addition to a default group.

Am I daydreaming? Is this foldable table achievable?

Comment: If you are, it is a wonderful daydream.  I would love to know myself, but could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with which we can get started attempting to make a dream become reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, I got to a decent solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{1}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6 \\\hline
a& b& c& d& e& f \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
1& 2& 3& 7& 8& 9 \\\hline
a& b& c& g& h& i \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
1& 2& 3& 10& 11& 12 \\\hline
a& b& c& j& k& l \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\newframe
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}\hline
1& 2& 3& 13& 14& 15 \\\hline
a& b& c& m& n& o \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

This adds animation control to scroll through the wide table, having the first three columns fixed. Still needs some enhancements to decrease the code size.

[image: Scrollable table]

Answer (score 3):

Here, I show the `usepartition` environment, operating on the same 15-column input, using the 4 separate partitions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,listofitems}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\NewEnviron{usepartion}[1]{%
  \tabtoks{}%
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist\mytab{\BODY}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\mytab{%
    \ifnum1=#1\relax%
      \edef\tmp{\mytab[\xcnt,1]&\mytab[\xcnt,2]&\mytab[\xcnt,3]&%
        \mytab[\xcnt,4]&\mytab[\xcnt,5]&\mytab[\xcnt,6]}%
    \else
    \ifnum2=#1\relax%
      \edef\tmp{\mytab[\xcnt,1]&\mytab[\xcnt,2]&\mytab[\xcnt,3]&%
        \mytab[\xcnt,7]&\mytab[\xcnt,8]&\mytab[\xcnt,9]}%
    \else
    \ifnum3=#1\relax%
      \edef\tmp{\mytab[\xcnt,1]&\mytab[\xcnt,2]&\mytab[\xcnt,3]&%
        \mytab[\xcnt,10]&\mytab[\xcnt,11]&\mytab[\xcnt,12]}%
    \else
    \ifnum4=#1\relax%
      \edef\tmp{\mytab[\xcnt,1]&\mytab[\xcnt,2]&\mytab[\xcnt,3]&%
        \mytab[\xcnt,13]&\mytab[\xcnt,14]&\mytab[\xcnt,15]}%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi%
    \expandafter\tabtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\the\expandafter\tabtoks\tmp\\}
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}
    \the\tabtoks
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{usepartion}{1}
1& 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14& 15\\
a& bb& ccc & d & ee & ff & ggg & hh & ii & j & k & lll & mm & nnn& o
\end{usepartion}

\begin{usepartion}{2}
1& 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14& 15\\
a& bb& ccc & d & ee & ff & ggg & hh & ii & j & k & lll & mm & nnn& o
\end{usepartion}

\begin{usepartion}{3}
1& 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14& 15\\
a& bb& ccc & d & ee & ff & ggg & hh & ii & j & k & lll & mm & nnn& o
\end{usepartion}

\begin{usepartion}{4}
1& 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14& 15\\
a& bb& ccc & d & ee & ff & ggg & hh & ii & j & k & lll & mm & nnn& o
\end{usepartion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More streamlined code, at the expense of one extra package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,listofitems,pgffor}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcounter{offset}
\NewEnviron{usepartion}[1]{%
  \tabtoks{}%
  \setcounter{offset}{0}%
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist\mytab{\BODY}%
  \foreach\y in {1,...,#1}{%
    \addtocounter{offset}{3}% 3 IS THE SIZE OF THE PARTITION GROUP
  }%   
  \foreachitem\x\in\mytab{%
    \edef\tmp{\mytab[\xcnt,1]&\mytab[\xcnt,2]&\mytab[\xcnt,3]&% COMMON PARTITION
                     \mytab[\xcnt,\numexpr\theoffset+1]&%
                     \mytab[\xcnt,\numexpr\theoffset+2]&%
                     \mytab[\xcnt,\numexpr\theoffset+3]}% SPECIFIED PARTITION
    \expandafter\tabtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\the\expandafter\tabtoks\tmp\\}% BUILD UP THE TOKEN LIST
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|}
    \the\tabtoks
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
\def\mydata{1& 2& 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14& 15\\
a& bb& ccc & d & ee & ff & ggg & hh & ii & j & k & lll & mm & nnn& o}
\begin{usepartion}{1}\mydata\end{usepartion}\par
\begin{usepartion}{2}\mydata\end{usepartion}\par
\begin{usepartion}{3}\mydata\end{usepartion}\par
\begin{usepartion}{4}\mydata\end{usepartion}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven, but this doesn't fulfill my need. I need to be able to fold/unfold parts of the table at read time. I thought about tikz or pstricks to do some hide/unhide layers with navigation buttons :-)

Comment: @TarekEldeeb At read time is a challenge.  I'm glad you resolved the issue elsewise.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TeXstudio, you can cut/paste columns and rows by going to : LaTeX - Manipulate tables - Remove column.

It has got a very nice wizard assistant (graphical interface) to draw tables ...

[image]

The hide/fold option haven't met it yet...

Comment: Thanks @Hamza, but this will only edit the table before generating the PDF.